# Изменить порядок вывода определенных значений SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с набором городов.Пытаюсь сделать `SELECT` запрос чтобы определенные города выводились самыми первыми в результате.При этом их порядок не должен быть нарушен(то есть как указали в запросе,в таком порядке и должны быть отображены)

Попробовал так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city,city_url
FROM cities
ORDER BY city IN ('Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Самара', 'Новосибирск', 'Нижний Новгород', 'Казань', 'Челябинск', 'Омск', 'Ростов-на-Дону', 'Уфа') DESC
```

Указанные города выводятся с самого начала, но не в том порядке,в котором надобно.

Скрин результатов запроса при использовании ответа @ilyaplot и варианта,указанного в вопросе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом,если убрать `DESC` или добавить `ASC`,то сортировка будет происходить просто по алфавиту.

Comment: Вижу на скрине, что сортировка по значению применилась, но в обратном порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте сортировку по значению

```
SELECT DISTINCT city,city_url FROM cities ORDER BY FIELD (city, 'Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Самара', 'Новосибирск', 'Нижний Новгород', 'Казань', 'Челябинск', 'Омск', 'Ростов-на-Дону', 'Уфа')
```

Но я рекомендую добавить поле sort_order, писать в него int и по нему сортировать. Так не придется при каждом запросе передавать порядок сортировки.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось:( Кстати,использовал это решение и оно работало только при передаче списка в `WHERE`

Comment: Название города в поле city лежит?

Comment: Верно,в поле `city`

Comment: Странно, я раньше делал сортировку по значению именно так, у меня работало прекрасно

Comment: Работает и без `where`,но порядок который указан в запросе не сохраняется как и в вопросе.

Comment: а вы не могли бы показать какой порядок

Comment: @Xramovnic Добавил скрин

Comment: Убрал DESC из запроса. Пропробуйте и вы.

Comment: @ilyaplot Пробовал. Просто сортировка по алфавиту:(

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вместе с сортировкой добавить условие where с теми значениями что указаны в сортировке, мне помогло отсортировать список в том порядке который мне был нужен на 200+ строк.

Comment: старайтесь давать чуть более концретные и точные ответы. В данном случае вы бы могли привести пример конкретного запроса, который иллюстрирует вашу мысль

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/781353)